# Populate NaN value in column A of data frame 1 with corresponding value from data frame 2 based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and am having a really difficult time with this. I have two data frames:

```
Df1
Address            Zip            Parcel Number
123 Main St        12345          1234-567-890
456 Broadway Ave   55555          NaN

Df2
Address            Zip            Parcel Number
456 Main St        66666          5555-555-555
456 Broadway Ave   55555          7777-777-777
```

What I would like to do is:
If the address & zip code columns in df1 are equal to the address & zip code columns of df2, populate the NaN value in the parcel number column of df1 with the corresponding parcel number value from df2.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called `combine_first`. Index your dataframes on ['Address', 'Zip'] first:

```
Df1.set_index(['Address', 'Zip'], inplace=True)
Df2.set_index(['Address', 'Zip'], inplace=True)
Df1.combine_first(Df2)
```

You can reset_index the resulting dataframe if you want to keep Address and Zip as columns

Comment: This was helpful, thank you! I didn't implement this solution exactly, but it did point me in the right direction. What I wound up doing was creating a new column in each data frame that combined the 'Address' and 'Zip' columns then merged the two data frames, on that new column, newdf = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Property Address Zip', how='inner'). After the merge I used .fillna to fill in the missing parcel numbers.